# if column not exists alter table

Tags: sql-server-2005, transactions, if-statement

I use the SQL script that was generated (sql 2k5), to add a column to a table.

I need to add a "check if exists" because my clients sometimes run the script twice. (i have no control over this part, and this is happening over and over again)

I found a way joining the sysobjects and syscolumns, it works.

My problem is that I have to add a column to an other table, where the column is not at the end of the table.

For this one, SQL is generating that long code ... create new temp table with the new column, filling up from old table, dropping the old table, and finally renaming the temp table.

The issue here is that the script for this one has lots of GO -s in there along with transactions ...

What can i do?

1.) remove all the GO - s? (don't like the idea)

2.) adding my IF between every GO pair? (don't like the idea)

3.) is there an other way that makes sense, and it would not be too hard to implement

I cannot think of anything really, I could check for release version, or anything, not just my sysobjects and syscolumns join, but the issue will be the same.

because of the GO-s, my If will be "forgotten" when it gets to the END of the BEGIN ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are they running the scripts (since you are using a tool which supports the GO batch separator) - SQL CMD?

I would consider putting it all in a string and using EXEC.  Several DDL commands have to be the first command in a batch.  Also, you can sometimes run into parsing issues:

[ALTER TABLE Executing regardless of Condition Evaluational Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017731/alter-table-executing-regardless-of-condition-evaluational-results)

Also, you may want to look at SQLCMD's control features http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/

Comment: sound interesting. will try, will let you know

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure I follow the entirety of your question, but you would check for the existence of a column like this:

```
if not exists (select * from information_schema.columns 
               where table_name = '[the tables name]' 
               and column_name = '[column name')
begin
 --alter table here
end
```

Why worry about the ordinal position of the column? New columns get a new colid and are appended to the "end", this shouldn't cause any problems.

If you make frequent updates by shipping these kinds of scripts, I would create a version table and just query this at the beginning of the script.

Comment: not possible. column order is set (hundreds of tables are the same and they HAVE to be the same)

Comment: Looks like you have bigger (design) problems than just adding some columns... Maybe you should first fix related code to not use selects and inserts without explicit column lists etc?

Comment: FYI The "end" is unrelated to on-disk structures of course. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839459/sql-server-performance-and-order-of-fields/5840669#5840669

Comment: I had to use the table and column names without the brackets.